What is the time complexity of populating a HashSet with n elements?
I was working on the Leetcode problem "Reverse Vowels of a String."
Here is my first solution:
class Solution {
    public String reverseVowels(String s) {
        String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

        int length = s.length();
        int i = 0;
        int j = length - 1;

        while(i < j & i < length & j > 0) {
            while(i < j && vowels.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
                i ++;
            }
            while(j > i && vowels.indexOf(arr[j]) == -1) {
                j --;
            }
            char temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i ++;
            j --;
        }

        return String.valueOf(arr);
    }
}


Since vowels.indexOf() has a time complexity of O(n), where n is the length of the vowels string, I decided to use a faster lookup data structure. Therefore, I implemented a HashSet as follows:
class Solution {
    public String reverseVowels(String s) {
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u'));
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

        int length = s.length();
        int i = 0;
        int j = length - 1;

        while(i < j & i < length & j > 0) {
            while(i < j && !set.contains(arr[i])) {
                i ++;
            }
            while(i < j && !set.contains(arr[j])) {
                j --;
            }
            char temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i ++;
            j --;
        }

        return String.valueOf(arr);
    }
}

My understanding is that constructing the HashSet with n characters has a time complexity of O(n), and each lookup is O(1). I expected this version to be faster. However, on Leetcode, the first solution finished in 3 ms, while the second one finished in 5 ms.
Why is the second one slower? What is the time complexity of constructing a HashSet with n elements, and how does it affect runtime in this case?

The timings on Leetcode are very inaccurate. I've often found different times when I ran the same code multiple times.

@k314159 With Java? For such short durations? I just submitted both five times, alternatingly. Results: 3, 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5 ms. Pretty consistent, as I had expected.

Constructing a HashSet does have O(n) performance, but you can't use the Big O notation to predict the runtime between different algorithms. You can't even use it to predict the runtime of add() and contain() in HashSet itself. From a benchmark in Baeldung



Benchmark
1000
10,000
100,000




.add()
0.026
0.023
0.024


.remove()
0.009
0.009
0.009


.contains()
0.009
0.009
0.010



Notice how both add() and contains() are O(1) (constant runtime regardless of collection size), but their runtime is different.
For very small input, the constant (not included in the Big O notation) overhead of a more complex algorithm likely exceeds the time saving for each operation. You'll only notice the difference once you crank the number to millions.

I see. I mistakenly used Big O to estimate the runtime, but Big O is actually meant to predict how an algorithm's runtime scales with the input size.

The second solution is slower despite using a HashSet for these reasons:
HashSet Overhead: Constructing the HashSet and calculating hash codes introduces extra overhead, even though lookups are O(1).
Small Set Size: The indexOf() in the first solution scans a small, constant set of 10 vowels, which is efficient. The linear search through a short string has minimal overhead.
Cache Efficiency: indexOf() operates on a small contiguous string, making it more cache-friendly than a HashSet, which has more complex memory access patterns.
Constant Factors: The overhead of HashSet operations (hashing, collision handling) can outweigh the benefits for such a small data set.
In summary, while HashSet has better theoretical complexity, the small set size and overhead make indexOf() faster in practice for this problem.
